# Cannot obtain value because it has been optimized away

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, clr

I have a problem with debugging...
All of a sudden I can't see the values of most variables while debugging.
I've managed to get two different messages in the Immediate Window:

> Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'parameter' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.

and

> Internal error in the expression evaluator.

I've tried and checked the following things:

1. Solution Configuration is set to debug (**not** release)
2. Project -> Settings -> Build -> Optimize code is **not** set
3. Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Use Managaed Compatibility Mode (didn't work)

Do you have any further ideas how I can properly debug again? :(

Thanks in advance

**Edit**
The code is nothing special.. it happens when I try to watch what's inside parameter[Key]

```
public void AddOrUpdateQuartzJob(string jobName, IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters)
    {
        var jobDetail = this.GetJobDetail(jobName);

        if (jobDetail != null)
        {
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                jobDetail.JobDataMap[parameter.Key] = parameter.Value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.ScheduleNewJob(jobName, parameters);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the original post

Comment: when you're in "if (jobDetail != null)". What's in parameters just before crash ?

Comment: I can't even see whats in parameters.. the same messages appear

Comment: Did you try to add "if (parameters != null)" before the for each ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best way I've found to [convince the JIT compiler not to optimize the code is to use an INI file with the name of the assembly in the same folder the assembly is in with the contents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8z24x(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[.NET Framework Debugging Control]
GenerateTrackingInfo=1
AllowOptimize=0
```

Note that it has to be the name of the assembly, not the name of the process EXE (unless it is the EXE assembly you want to debug). E.g. if you have an assembly `MyCode.dll` the INI file name would be `MyCode.ini`.

Here are some slides from [a presentation on .Net debugging](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=739DCC71898E38F9!447479&ithint=file%2cpptx&app=PowerPoint&authkey=!AJ-STUxCJ61U-a0) which show the difference:

**With Optimization:**

[image: Debugging with optimization]

**Without Optimization:**

[image: Debugging without optimization]

Comment: i tried hundred other ways.This way worked.weird but thank you.

Comment: I found the following to work without creating a file for every project. In Visual Studio (2019), under Tools menu, Options -> Debugging -> General -> make sure "Suppress JIT optimization on module load (Managed only)" is checked.

Comment: @SteveB - yup that sometimes works, but for some reason not all the time.

Comment: Seems this method is really needed when using, say dnspy for example, when debugging production builds.

Answer (score 4):

Go to -> Project Properties -> under Build -> set "Optimize Code" checkbox Unchecked.

Also, 
Under Project Properties -> Build ->  Advanced -> set the "Debug Info" dropdown to "Full" in the Options

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who was stumped on this, you may be making the same simple mistake I was: my build mode was set to Release from another project I had to build for release earlier in the day. Flip it back to Debug; problem solved.

Comment: my "active" configuration is set to Release however. It is not shown from the visual studio UI. It is fixed when I changed from the configuration manager. I took this project from someone else so I had no idea why it was set this way.

Comment: This issue also occurs when activemode is set to Debug and the "Optimize Code" setting is selected for Debug. @isanka thalagala has an answer posted that addresses this common 'mis-click'

Answer (score 2):

After making the changes listed by codekaizen and isanka thalagala, do not forget to clean, rebuild and publish to make the changes effective.